# Mutual SSL auth fail at handshake

Tags: tomcat, ssl, cxf, mutual-authentication

I'm trying to connect to a web service protected by mutual authentication.

I'm using cxf web client and the client is configured like below

```
      KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
      KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
      String keystorepass = "***";
      String trustpass = "***";
      File truststore = new File("trustfile");
      File keystoreFile = new File("keyfile");
      keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile), keystorepass.toCharArray());
      trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(truststore), trustpass.toCharArray());

      tlsParams.setDisableCNCheck(true);
      tlsParams.setSecureSocketProtocol("TLSv1.2");
      TrustManagerFactory trustFactory = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
      trustFactory.init(trustStore);
      TrustManager[] tm = trustFactory.getTrustManagers();
      tlsParams.setTrustManagers(tm);
      KeyManagerFactory keyFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
      keyFactory.init(keyStore, keystorepass.toCharArray());
      KeyManager[] km = keyFactory.getKeyManagers();
      tlsParams.setKeyManagers(km);
      FiltersType filter = new FiltersType();
      filter.getInclude().add(".*_WITH_AES_.*");
      filter.getExclude().add(".*_DH_anon_.*");
      tlsParams.setCipherSuitesFilter(filter);
```

the webclient code that actually sends the message to server is as below

```
 WebClient client = WebClient.create(tallyEndPoint);
client.path(partnerAuthUrl);
ClientConfiguration config = WebClient.getConfig(client);
config.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
config.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
HTTPConduit conduit =
    (HTTPConduit) WebClient.getConfig(client).getConduit();
HTTPClientPolicy policy = conduit.getClient();
policy.setProxyServer(proxyUrl);
policy.setProxyServerPort(proxyPort);
conduit.setTlsClientParameters(tlsParams);    
MultivaluedMap<String, String> formParams = new MultivaluedHashMap<>();
formParams.add("***", "***");
Form postForm = new Form(formParams);
client.type(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED_TYPE);
Response response = client.form(postForm);enter code here
```

from the server side packet capture I can see, following messages

- client hello - 141    *** 192.*** 10.***  TLSv1.2 414 Client Hello
- server ack
- server hello 143  *** 10.***  198.*** TLSv1.2 1575    Server Hello
- server ack
- server cert, key exchange and cert request - 145  *** 10.***  198.*** TLSv1.2 1267    Certificate, Server Key Exchange, Certificate Request, Server Hello Done
- client ack
- client ack
- client reset ack 148  ****    198.*** 10.***  TCP 115 58308 → 443 [RST, ACK] Seq=288 Ack=4037 Win=65535 Len=0

I have enabled the SSL debug in the client and I see certificate change message being logged

I can see following actions are happening

- ClientHello, TLSv1.2
- ServerHello, TLSv1.2
- Certificate chain
- ECDH ServerKeyExchange
- ServerHelloDone
- ECDHClientKeyExchange
- ClientHello, TLSv1.2

after the last clientHello I'm being disconnected

> tomcat-http--1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Handshake, length = 282
>
> tomcat-http--1, handling exception: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>
> tomcat-http--1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = unexpected_message
>
> tomcat-http--1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
>
> tomcat-http--1, Exception sending alert: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
>
> tomcat-http--1, called closeSocket()
>
> tomcat-http--1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Application Data, length = 472
>
> tomcat-http--1, called close()
>
> tomcat-http--1, called closeInternal(true)
>
> tomcat-http--1, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  warning, description = close_notify
>
> tomcat-http--1, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 26
>
> tomcat-http--1, called closeSocket(true)

I do have the keystore with my private key and a truststore with the servers key chain added and configured.

Any help would be greatly appriciated

Comment: Please take some time to format your question as it is very difficult to read right now. Also you may not be exactly on topic here since it is not related to programming per se (you show no code indeed). Have a look instead at [sf] for example or even [webmasters.se] (read their help and tour sections to assess if you are ontopic or not). Also generic advice for TLS troubleshooting: did you try using another client/another server just to pinpoint where the problem is? When the problem started? Does the result changed based on certificates used? etc. (make sure to use SNI!)

Comment: added the code and removed most of the ssl debug logs. hope this helps